# powershell smtp has no mailbox associated with it

Tags: web-services, powershell, calendar, exchange-server-2010

I am trying to input an appointment into calendar in exchange 2010 using powershell. But i get an error on the last line to save. the smtp has no mailbox associated with it. I am using admin user to do this so i don't understand why it is not working. below is the code

```
Param ([string]$calInputFile = $(throw "Please provide calendar input file..."))

# Testing
#$calinputfile="d:\calendar_inject.csv"
# Connect to Live@edu
# capture the admin LiveID username in a variable
$Username = "administrator@domainasa.com"
# capture the admin LiveID password in a variable.  Note, that it is stored as a secure string
$Password = ConvertTo-SecureString ‘password’ -AsPlainText -Force
# populate the $Livecred PowerShell credential with $Username and $Password
$Livecred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $Username, $Password
#$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://thor.uk.domainasa.com/powershell/ -Credential $LiveCred -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
#Import-PSSession $Session
# Load EWS Managed API library
Import-Module -Name "C:\Program Files\Symantec\Backup Exec\Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll"
# Load all Mailboxes
#$exchangeUsers = Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited | Select UserPrincipalName
#test with just one user
$exchangeusers = get-mailbox "sharif uddin" |select UserPrincipalName
# Load all calendar Entries
$calEntries = Import-Csv $calInputFile
# Identify the folder to save our appointments into
$folderid = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderId([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WellKnownFolderName]::Calendar)
# Create Exchange Service object
$service = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Exchangeversion]::exchange2010)
$service.Url = new-object System.Uri("https://thor.uk.domainasa.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx")
# Service account must have ApplicationImpersonation ManagementRoleAssignment in Exchange
$service.Credentials = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WebCredentials("administrator@domainasa.com","woki1141")

foreach($mailbox in $exchangeUsers)
{
 # Identify user to which appointment will be added
  $MailboxName = $mailbox.UserPrincipalName
  # Instruct service to use impersonation
  $iUserID = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ImpersonatedUserId([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ConnectingIdType]::SmtpAddress,$MailboxName)
  #Write-Output $iUserID
  $service.ImpersonatedUserId = $iUserID
  Write-Output $service

  # Create new appointment object for each appointment to save
  foreach($entry in $calEntries)
  {
   $appt = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Appointment($service)
   $appt.Subject = $entry.Subject

   # Convert date
   $x = Get-Date -Date $entry."Start Date"
   $y = Get-Date -Date $entry."End Date"
   $appt.Start = [System.DateTime]( $x )
   $appt.End = [System.DateTime]($y)    #For AllDayEvent, end date must be after start date
   $appt.IsAllDayEvent = $True
   $appt.LegacyFreeBusyStatus = "Free"
   $appt.IsReminderSet = $False   #If you want a reminder then remove this line
   #$appt.Save($folderid)
   $appt.Save()
  }
}
```

ERROR:

```
Exception calling "Save" with "0" argument(s): "The SMTP address has no mailbox associated with it."
At C:\exchange.ps1:55 char:14
+    $appt.Save <<<< ()
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the mailbox does exist and whether the alias is correct.

Comment: Got it working now `$iUserID = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ImpersonatedUserId([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ConnectingIdType]::SmtpAddress,$email)
  $service.ImpersonatedUserId = $iUserID`