# The SMTP address has no mailbox associated with it using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices

Tags: authentication, smtp

I have tried the below code. As I already have my account on this server, I'm getting the error mentioned in the subject.

```
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010);
        service.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("****", "*****", "*****");

        service.Url = new Uri("https://******/ews/exchange.asmx");

        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };

        FindItemsResults<Item> findResults = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, new ItemView(1));

        foreach (Item item in findResults.Items)
        {
            if (item.HasAttachments && item.Attachments[0] is FileAttachment)
            {
                FileAttachment fileAttachment = item.Attachments[0] as FileAttachment;
                fileAttachment.Load(@"\\c:\\filesave\\" + fileAttachment.Name);
            }

        }
```

Thanks,
Kandarp

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to update your exchange Server? (Are you running an 2013 Server?)

While I ran in this error too, I search a while and found [this](https://cs.mailstore.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/112/4/ews-error-code-errornonexistentmailbox)

Maybe you check if [this update](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3006861) is already live on your system.

Anyway this solved my problem

Comment: hi @kandarp parikh, did this one solve your issue? please kindly answer back, as i am experiencing it on a 2010 server, not 2013

Comment: will this patch be compatible for exchange server 2010?

Comment: @allenj unfortunately I didn't find any patch for server 2010.
Take a look [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/de3c268b-576c-4513-bf70-d0495afba983/getuseroofsettings-web-service-throws-the-smtp-address-has-no-mailbox-associated-with-it-exception?forum=exchange2010) and [here](https://community.bittitan.com/kb/Pages/The%20SMTP%20address%20has%20no%20mailbox%20associated%20with%20it.aspx) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10736551/powershell-smtp-has-no-mailbox-associated-with-it) stackoverflow question - hopefully this can help you

Comment: thanks for your reply. i just received from my client that the 2013 comulative update works and fixed the issue on a 2010 server